# (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address xx.xxx.xxx.xx:80

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ip, xampp, lamp

I am trying to configure access over Internet for xampp under Ubuntu. All works fine but when I add: `Listen myip:80` in httpd.conf I cannot start apache server again. This is the error shown in /opt/lampp/logs/error_log:

```
(99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address xx.xxx.xxx.xx:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I cannot start Apache only if I add `Listen xx.xxx.xxx.xx:80`. If I change the `Listen 80` to `Listen 1234` or another port it runs ok. The problem seems to exist only if I add an IP.

I found this comment over the internet but I have no idea how to do it for xampp:
"The problem was the additional network cards were not configure with the addition IP's."

Also running from root `netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'` does not show anything.

I do not have Skype installed and it seems that there is no other process running on port 80.

Any ideas why this could be or how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get this working. I turned out I had not properly configured the forwarding of the IP from my outside address to the local IP address obtained by the Virtualbox.

I was using a Bridged Adapter, when I should have used a NAT connection and forward the outside IP to the Virtual box IP.

Hope this answer helps others with similar issue.